# Getting 404 on buddypress submenu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, buddypress

Hi Ive been trying to work this out for a while now and searching all through google and everywhere.

I have created a new menu item in the profile area of buddypress. when I click on the new main menu item it goes to the proper function/page, but when I click on the sub menu item it goes to a 404 page.

I know the sub menu is processing the function but it seems the slug goes to a 404 page. Here is the code I have put in bp-custom.php

```
function profile_new_nav_item() {

    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_nav_item(
    array(
        'name'                => 'eBlurts',
        'slug'                => 'eblurts',
        'default_subnav_slug' => 'eblurt-activity', // We add this submenu item below 
        'screen_function'     => 'view_manage_tab_main'
    )
    );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_nav_item', 10 );

function view_manage_tab_main() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'bp_template_content_main_function' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
}

function bp_template_content_main_function() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) );
    }
}

function profile_new_subnav_item() {
    global $bp;

    bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
        'name'            => 'eBlurt Activity',
        'slug'            => 'eblurt-activity',
        'parent_url'      => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->bp_nav[ 'eblurts' ][ 'slug' ] . '/',
        'parent_slug'     => $bp->bp_nav[ 'eblurts' ][ 'slug' ],
        'position'        => 10,
        'screen_function' => 'eblurt_activity'
        //'link' => bp_get_activity_directory_permalink()
    ) );

    bp_core_new_subnav_item( array(
        'name'            => 'Write eBlurt',
        'slug'            => 'write-eBlurt',
        'parent_url'      => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->bp_nav[ 'eblurts' ][ 'slug' ] . '/',
        'parent_slug'     => $bp->bp_nav[ 'eblurts' ][ 'slug' ],
        'position'        => 20,
        'screen_function' => 'write_eblurt'
        //'link' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->bp_nav[ 'eblurts' ][ 'slug' ] . '/write-eBlurt/'
    ) );
}

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_new_subnav_item', 10 );

function eblurt_activity() {
    //bp_get_template_part( 'template_content' );
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'eblurt_content' );
    //bp_get_template_part( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/plugins' ) );
    //bp_get_template_part( 'eblurts' );
    //echo 'has it reached here';
}
function write_eblurt() {
    //echo 'here now';
   //bp_get_template_part( 'template_content' );
    bp_get_template_part( 'members/single/plugins' );
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'eblurt_content' );
    //bp_core_redirect( get_option('siteurl') . "/videos/" );

    //echo 'this is where it is';
    //bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
    //bp_get_template_part( 'eblurts' );

}
function eblurt_content(){
bp_get_template_part( 'eblurts' );
}
```

I left some of the things I have tried in comments. Also I put the file "eblurts.php" in my theme folder. It does seem to be reaching it because it is echoing the text that is in the file.

Any help or things to try would be appreciated I going crazy lol. Or if there might be a better way to do what I want, which is basically --- Have a menu item in the profile area that goes to a page where I have a form for user to submit 
some stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course I look for the past couple day on why this isnt working and an hour after posting this question I figured it out.

Well anyways what it was is in the function for your submenu you have to use "bp_core_load_template" NOT "bp_get_template_part"

Changed:

```
bp_get_template_part( 'template_content' );
```

TO:

```
bp_core_load_template( 'template_content' );
```

So hopefully the few people that got the same error this will help out.